# How to make images fit the shape of each US state

Tags: r, loops, maps, image-scaling

[image: So, the following graph is the inspiration for this post.]

I want to utilize my data to see which sports teams are selling the most trading cards by state - and have the brand image file in each respective state.

So far, I've modified my code up to this point:

```
library(USAboundaries)
#> The USAboundariesData package needs to be installed.
#>  Please try installing the package using the following command: 
#>      install.packages("USAboundariesData", repos = "https://ropensci.r-universe.dev", type = "source")
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.1, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(tidyverse)
library(rasterpic)
library(tidyterra)

states <- USAboundaries::states_contemporary_lores %>%
  select(State = state_abbr) %>%
  # Filter AK and HW
  filter(!(State %in% c("AK", "HI", "PR"))) %>%
  st_transform("ESRI:102003") 

states

plot <- ggplot(states) +
  geom_sf(fill = "white") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "lightblue1"))

plot

teams <- data.frame(State = January$ShipState)
teams$Team <- data.frame(Team = January$Team)

logos <- c("Kansas City Chiefs" = "https://wpcdn.us-east-1.vip.tn-cloud.net/www.koamnewsnow.com/content/uploads/2019/12/17535504_g_23777296_ver1-0.png",
           "Alabama Crimson Tide" = "https://seeklogo.com/images/A/alabama-crimson-tide-logo-CBD5086B7E-seeklogo.com.png",
           "Phoenix Suns" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/58419d52a6515b1e0ad75a6d.png",
           "San Francisco 49ers" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b55.png", 
           "Colorado Avalanche" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/5a4fbb29da2b4f099b95da0b.png", 
           "Tampa Bay Buccaneers" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/thumbs/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b5e.png", 
           "Washington Capitals" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/5a4fbbeada2b4f099b95da22.png",
           "Philadelphia Eagles" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/thumbs/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b4b.png",
           "Georgia Bulldogs" = "https://flyclipart.com/thumb2/logo-university-of-georgia-bulldogs-bulldog-head-585520.png",
           "Chicago Bears" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/chicago-bears-logo-transparent.png", 
           "Cincinnati Bengals" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b19.png", 
           "New Orleans Saints" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/new-orleans-saints-logo-transparent.png",
           "Baltimore Ravens" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/baltimore-ravens-logo-transparent.png",
           "Minnesota Wild" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/5a4fbb61da2b4f099b95da12.png",
           "Vegas Golden Knights" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/5a4fbbe1da2b4f099b95da21.png",
           "Buffalo Bills" = "https://seeklogo.com/images/B/buffalo-bills-logo-8924E7DD74-seeklogo.com.png",
           "Pittsburgh Steelers" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b4e.png",
           "Tennessee Titans" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b61.png",
           "Dallas Cowboys"= 'https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/dallas-cowboys-logo-transparent.png',
           "Seattle Seahawks" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/seattle-seahawks-logo-transparent.png",
           "Green Bay Packers" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b25.png",
           "West Virginia Mountaineers" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/west-virginia-mountaineers-logo-png-transparent.png",
           "Arkansas Razorbacks" = "https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/287-2878486_picture-arkansas-razorbacks-logo-hd-png-download.png",
           "La Rams" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/608968b9d598a5000448eaa2.png",
           "Washington Commanders" = "https://loodibee.com/wp-content/uploads/washington-commanders-logo.png",
           "Philadelphia 76ers" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/58419ca3a6515b1e0ad75a64.png",
           "Charlotte Fc" = "https://logowik.com/content/uploads/images/charlotte-football-club2631.jpg",
           "Nebraska Cornhuskers" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/nebraska-corn-huskers-logo-png-transparent.png",
           "New York Yankees" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d4b740a44bd1070d5d494.png",
           "Oklahoma Sooners" = "https://1000logos.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Oklahoma-Sooners-logo.png",
           "Milwaukee Brewers" = "https://purepng.com/public/uploads/large/milwaukee-brewers-logo-9xg.png",
           "Los Angeles Dodgers" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d3e8a0a44bd1070d5d3d7.png",
           "Denver Broncos" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/denver-broncos-logo-transparent.png",
           "Washington Nationals" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/washington-nationals-logo-transparent.png",
           "Philadelphia Phillies" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d42ac0a44bd1070d5d420.png",
           "Atlanta Braves" = "https://1000logos.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Atlanta-Braves-logo.png",
           "Iowa Hawkeyes" = "https://1000logos.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Iowa-Hawkeyes-logo.png",
           "Gonzaga University Bulldogs" = "https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/65-655460_bulldog-700x441-gonzaga-bulldog.png",
           "Chicago Cubs" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d41b10a44bd1070d5d411.png",
           "Kentucky Wildcats" = "https://1000logos.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Kentucky-Wildcats-logo.png",
           "Lsu Tigers" = "https://www.nicepng.com/png/full/96-961386_lsu-football-png-transparent-lsu-football-louisiana-state.png",
           "Boston Red Sox"= "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/boston-red-sox-logo-transparent.png",
           "Detroit Tigers" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/detroit-tigers-logo-transparent.png",
           "Minnesota Twins" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d47ae0a44bd1070d5d45d.png",
           "St Louis Cardinals" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d3fc80a44bd1070d5d3ed.png",
           "Mississippi State Bulldogs" = "https://www.nicepng.com/png/detail/71-714091_logo-university-bulldogs-ring-bulldoghead-mississippi-state-university.png",
           "Cleveland Browns" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/cleveland-browns-logo-transparent.png",
           "Portland Trailblazers" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/portland-trail-blazers-logo-transparent.png",
           "Masters" = "https://logos-world.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Masters-Symbol.png",
           "Tennessee Vols" = "https://1000logos.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Tennessee-Volunteers-logo.png",
           "Houston Astros"= "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d493b0a44bd1070d5d477.png",
           "Utah Jazz" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/58419bb6a6515b1e0ad75a55.png",
           "La Lakers" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/58419d0aa6515b1e0ad75a6c.png",
           "Kansas Jayhawks" = "https://brandslogos.com/wp-content/uploads/images/large/kansas-jayhawks-logo.png",
           "Baltimore Orioles" = "https://logos-world.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Baltimore-Orioles-Logo-2019-Present.png",
           "Unc Tar Heels" = "https://logos-world.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/North-Carolina-Tar-Heels-Logo-2005-2014.png",
           "South Carolina Gamecocks" = "https://sportslogohistory.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/south_carolina_gamecocks_1983-pres_s.png",
           "Seattle Mariners" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d467c0a44bd1070d5d44c.png",
           "Colorado Rockies" = "https://www.nicepng.com/png/full/141-1415329_colorado-rockies-logos-png-clipart-download-colorado-rockies.png",
           "Golden State Warriors" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/58419ce2a6515b1e0ad75a69.png",
           "Chicago White Sox" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d4aff0a44bd1070d5d48d.png",
           "Boston Celtics" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/58419c6aa6515b1e0ad75a61.png",
           "Carolina Hurricanes" = "https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/carolina-hurricanes-nhl-logo-png-11536005105kxafnwdw2o.png",
           "Tampa Bay Lightning" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/5a4fbbc8da2b4f099b95da1e.png",
           "Oregon Ducks" = "https://1000logos.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Oregon-Ducks-logo.png",
           "Milwaukee Bucks" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/58419ba7a6515b1e0ad75a54.png",
           "Los Angeles Angels" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d498d0a44bd1070d5d47b.png",
           "Carolina Panthers" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/carolina-panthers-logo-transparent.png",
           "Minnesota Vikings" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b38.png",
           "New England Patriots" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b3b.png",
           "Clemson Tigers" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/61487c1ad329bb0004dbd32d.png",
           "Wyoming Cowboys" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/wyoming-cowboys-logo-png-transparent.png",
           "Arizona Cardinals" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/arizona-cardinals-logo-transparent.png",
           "Washington Football Team" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/60896cf3d598a5000448eaa8.png",
           "Indianapolis Colts" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b2c.png",
           "Detroit Lions" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/detroit-lions-logo-transparent.png",
           "Las Vegas Raiders" = "https://www.pngmart.com/files/16/Las-Vegas-Raiders-Transparent-Background.png",
           "Michigan State Spartans" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/6103b47a2d29570004bc56f2.png",
           "Utah Utes" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/5859a2df4f6ae202fedf28ec.png",
           "Seattle Kraken" = "https://brandlogos.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/seattle_kraken-logo-brandlogos.net_-512x512.png",
           "Michigan Wolverines" = "https://stateofmisports.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/michigan_wolverines-1.png")

states <- states[states$State != "DC",]

for (i in seq(nrow(states))) {
  logo <- logos$png[logos$State == states$State[i]]
  shape <- states[i, ] 
  img <- rasterpic_img(shape, logo, mask = TRUE)
  plot <- plot + geom_spatraster_rgb(data = img)
}
plot
```

[image: Where you can see the images are far too large.]

All of this should be fitting more like the example photo

Edited in the January dataset

```
ShipState   Team
AL  Alabama Crimson Tide
AR  Kansas City Chiefs
AZ  Phoenix Suns
CA  San Francisco 49ers
CO  Colorado Avalanche
CT  Tampa Bay Buccaneers
DE  Philadelphia Eagles
FL  Tampa Bay Buccaneers
GA  Georgia Bulldogs
IA  Kansas City Chiefs
ID  San Francisco 49ers
IL  Chicago Bears
IN  Cincinnati Bengals
KS  Kansas City Chiefs
KY  Cincinnati Bengals
LA  New Orleans Saints
MA  Tampa Bay Buccaneers
MD  Baltimore Ravens
ME  Tampa Bay Buccaneers
MI  Tampa Bay Buccaneers
MN  Minnesota Wild
MO  Kansas City Chiefs
MS  Alabama Crimson Tide
MT  Kansas City Chiefs
NC  Georgia Bulldogs
ND  Kansas City Chiefs
NE  Kansas City Chiefs
NH  Tampa Bay Buccaneers
NJ  Tampa Bay Buccaneers
NM  San Francisco 49ers
NV  Vegas Golden Knights
NY  Buffalo Bills
OH  Cincinnati Bengals
OK  Kansas City Chiefs
OR  San Francisco 49ers
PA  Pittsburgh Steelers
RI  Tampa Bay Buccaneers
SC  Georgia Bulldogs
SD  Kansas City Chiefs
TN  Tennessee Titans
TX  Dallas Cowboys
UT  Kansas City Chiefs
VA  Washington Capitals
VI  Tampa Bay Buccaneers
VT  Tampa Bay Buccaneers
WA  Seattle Seahawks
WI  Green Bay Packers
WV  West Virginia Mountaineers
WY  Buffalo Bills
```

Output now gives the following error. "Error: $ Operator is invalid for atomic vectors." I believe I may need to get rid of something? But I'm unsure what.

Comment: Please don't post [duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72540753/logo-plots-on-us-map-in-r-are-way-too-large).

Comment: Then help, please. It is not a 1:1 duplicate either - there is a new issue with the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea. Your loop is letting you down though. First, remove DC from the `states` data frame too, since it has no entry in `January`. Then your loop should be:

```r
states <- states[states$State != "DC",]

for (i in seq(nrow(states))) {
  logo <- logos$png[logos$State == states$State[i]]
  shape <- states[i, ] 
  img <- rasterpic_img(shape, logo, mask = TRUE)
  plot <- plot + geom_spatraster_rgb(data = img)
}
```

Resulting in

```r
plot
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

To remove all confusion, the following script is a fully reproducible example. Anyone starting with a fresh R session will be able to reproduce the plot with exactly this script (the data is included in it)

```r
library(USAboundaries) 
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(rasterpic)
library(tidyterra)

January <- structure(list(ShipState = c("AL", "AR", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "CT", 
"DE", "FL", "GA", "IA", "ID", "IL", "IN", "KS", "KY", "LA", "MA", 
"MD", "ME", "MI", "MN", "MO", "MS", "MT", "NC", "ND", "NE", "NH", 
"NJ", "NM", "NV", "NY", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", 
"TN", "TX", "UT", "VA", "VI", "VT", "WA", "WI", "WV", "WY"), 
    Team = c("Alabama Crimson Tide", "Kansas City Chiefs", "Phoenix Suns", 
    "San Francisco 49ers", "Colorado Avalanche", "Tampa Bay Buccaneers", 
    "Philadelphia Eagles", "Tampa Bay Buccaneers", "Georgia Bulldogs", 
    "Kansas City Chiefs", "San Francisco 49ers", "Chicago Bears", 
    "Cincinnati Bengals", "Kansas City Chiefs", "Cincinnati Bengals", 
    "New Orleans Saints", "Tampa Bay Buccaneers", "Baltimore Ravens", 
    "Tampa Bay Buccaneers", "Tampa Bay Buccaneers", "Minnesota Wild", 
    "Kansas City Chiefs", "Alabama Crimson Tide", "Kansas City Chiefs", 
    "Georgia Bulldogs", "Kansas City Chiefs", "Kansas City Chiefs", 
    "Tampa Bay Buccaneers", "Tampa Bay Buccaneers", "San Francisco 49ers", 
    "Vegas Golden Knights", "Buffalo Bills", "Cincinnati Bengals", 
    "Kansas City Chiefs", "San Francisco 49ers", "Pittsburgh Steelers", 
    "Tampa Bay Buccaneers", "Georgia Bulldogs", "Kansas City Chiefs", 
    "Tennessee Titans", "Dallas Cowboys", "Kansas City Chiefs", 
    "Washington Capitals", "Tampa Bay Buccaneers", "Tampa Bay Buccaneers", 
    "Seattle Seahawks", "Green Bay Packers", "West Virginia Mountaineers", 
    "Buffalo Bills")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-49L))

states <- USAboundaries::states_contemporary_lores %>%
  select(State = state_abbr) %>%
  filter(!(State %in% c("AK", "HI", "PR", "DC"))) %>%
  st_transform("ESRI:102003") 

plot <- ggplot(states) +
  geom_sf(fill = "white") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "lightblue1"))

teams <- data.frame(State = January$ShipState)
teams$Team <- data.frame(Team = January$Team)

logos <- teams %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(png = switch(Team$Team,
                      "Kansas City Chiefs" = "https://wpcdn.us-east-1.vip.tn-cloud.net/www.koamnewsnow.com/content/uploads/2019/12/17535504_g_23777296_ver1-0.png",
                      "Alabama Crimson Tide" = "https://seeklogo.com/images/A/alabama-crimson-tide-logo-CBD5086B7E-seeklogo.com.png",
                      "Phoenix Suns" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/58419d52a6515b1e0ad75a6d.png",
                      "San Francisco 49ers" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b55.png", 
                      "Colorado Avalanche" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/5a4fbb29da2b4f099b95da0b.png", 
                      "Tampa Bay Buccaneers" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/thumbs/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b5e.png", 
                      "Washington Capitals" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/5a4fbbeada2b4f099b95da22.png",
                      "Philadelphia Eagles" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/thumbs/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b4b.png",
                      "Georgia Bulldogs" = "https://flyclipart.com/thumb2/logo-university-of-georgia-bulldogs-bulldog-head-585520.png",
                      "Chicago Bears" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/chicago-bears-logo-transparent.png", 
                      "Cincinnati Bengals" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b19.png", 
                      "New Orleans Saints" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/new-orleans-saints-logo-transparent.png",
                      "Baltimore Ravens" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/baltimore-ravens-logo-transparent.png",
                      "Minnesota Wild" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/5a4fbb61da2b4f099b95da12.png",
                      "Vegas Golden Knights" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/5a4fbbe1da2b4f099b95da21.png",
                      "Buffalo Bills" = "https://seeklogo.com/images/B/buffalo-bills-logo-8924E7DD74-seeklogo.com.png",
                      "Pittsburgh Steelers" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b4e.png",
                      "Tennessee Titans" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b61.png",
                      "Dallas Cowboys"= 'https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/dallas-cowboys-logo-transparent.png',
                      "Seattle Seahawks" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/seattle-seahawks-logo-transparent.png",
                      "Green Bay Packers" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b25.png",
                      "West Virginia Mountaineers" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/west-virginia-mountaineers-logo-png-transparent.png",
                      "Arkansas Razorbacks" = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ef/Arkansas-Razorback-Logo-2001.png",
                      "La Rams" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/608968b9d598a5000448eaa2.png",
                      "Washington Commanders" = "https://loodibee.com/wp-content/uploads/washington-commanders-logo.png",
                      "Philadelphia 76ers" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/58419ca3a6515b1e0ad75a64.png",
                      "Charlotte Fc" = "https://freetipscout.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/sorarecharlottefclogo.png",
                      "Nebraska Cornhuskers" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/nebraska-corn-huskers-logo-png-transparent.png",
                      "New York Yankees" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d4b740a44bd1070d5d494.png",
                      "Oklahoma Sooners" = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/49/Oklahoma_Sooners_logo.png",
                      "Milwaukee Brewers" = "https://purepng.com/public/uploads/large/milwaukee-brewers-logo-9xg.png",
                      "Los Angeles Dodgers" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d3e8a0a44bd1070d5d3d7.png",
                      "Denver Broncos" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/denver-broncos-logo-transparent.png",
                      "Washington Nationals" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/washington-nationals-logo-transparent.png",
                      "Philadelphia Phillies" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d42ac0a44bd1070d5d420.png",
                      "Atlanta Braves" = "https://1000logos.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Atlanta-Braves-logo.png",
                      "Iowa Hawkeyes" = "https://1000logos.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Iowa-Hawkeyes-logo.png",
                      "Gonzaga University Bulldogs" = "https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/65-655460_bulldog-700x441-gonzaga-bulldog.png",
                      "Chicago Cubs" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d41b10a44bd1070d5d411.png",
                      "Kentucky Wildcats" = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Kentucky_Wildcats_logo_2015.png",
                      "Lsu Tigers" = "https://www.nicepng.com/png/full/96-961386_lsu-football-png-transparent-lsu-football-louisiana-state.png",
                      "Boston Red Sox"= "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/boston-red-sox-logo-transparent.png",
                      "Detroit Tigers" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/detroit-tigers-logo-transparent.png",
                      "Minnesota Twins" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d47ae0a44bd1070d5d45d.png",
                      "St Louis Cardinals" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d3fc80a44bd1070d5d3ed.png",
                      "Mississippi State Bulldogs" = "https://www.nicepng.com/png/detail/71-714091_logo-university-bulldogs-ring-bulldoghead-mississippi-state-university.png",
                      "Cleveland Browns" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/cleveland-browns-logo-transparent.png",
                      "Portland Trailblazers" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/portland-trail-blazers-logo-transparent.png",
                      "Masters" = "https://logos-world.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Masters-Symbol.png",
                      "Tennessee Vols" = "https://1000logos.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Tennessee-Volunteers-logo.png",
                      "Houston Astros"= "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d493b0a44bd1070d5d477.png",
                      "Utah Jazz" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/58419bb6a6515b1e0ad75a55.png",
                      "La Lakers" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/58419d0aa6515b1e0ad75a6c.png",
                      "Kansas Jayhawks" = "https://brandslogos.com/wp-content/uploads/images/large/kansas-jayhawks-logo.png",
                      "Baltimore Orioles" = "https://logos-world.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Baltimore-Orioles-Logo-2019-Present.png",
                      "Unc Tar Heels" = "https://logos-world.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/North-Carolina-Tar-Heels-Logo-2005-2014.png",
                      "South Carolina Gamecocks" = "https://sportslogohistory.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/south_carolina_gamecocks_1983-pres_s.png",
                      "Seattle Mariners" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d467c0a44bd1070d5d44c.png",
                      "Colorado Rockies" = "https://www.nicepng.com/png/full/141-1415329_colorado-rockies-logos-png-clipart-download-colorado-rockies.png",
                      "Golden State Warriors" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/58419ce2a6515b1e0ad75a69.png",
                      "Chicago White Sox" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d4aff0a44bd1070d5d48d.png",
                      "Boston Celtics" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/58419c6aa6515b1e0ad75a61.png",
                      "Carolina Hurricanes" = "https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/carolina-hurricanes-nhl-logo-png-11536005105kxafnwdw2o.png",
                      "Tampa Bay Lightning" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/5a4fbbc8da2b4f099b95da1e.png",
                      "Oregon Ducks" = "https://dejpknyizje2n.cloudfront.net/gallery/Ducks.png",
                      "Milwaukee Bucks" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/58419ba7a6515b1e0ad75a54.png",
                      "Los Angeles Angels" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/584d498d0a44bd1070d5d47b.png",
                      "Carolina Panthers" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/carolina-panthers-logo-transparent.png",
                      "Minnesota Vikings" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b38.png",
                      "New England Patriots" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b3b.png",
                      "Clemson Tigers" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/61487c1ad329bb0004dbd32d.png",
                      "Wyoming Cowboys" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/wyoming-cowboys-logo-png-transparent.png",
                      "Arizona Cardinals" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/arizona-cardinals-logo-transparent.png",
                      "Washington Football Team" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/60896cf3d598a5000448eaa8.png",
                      "Indianapolis Colts" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b2b2c.png",
                      "Detroit Lions" = "https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/images/large/2x/detroit-lions-logo-transparent.png",
                      "Las Vegas Raiders" = "https://www.pngmart.com/files/16/Las-Vegas-Raiders-Transparent-Background.png",
                      "Michigan State Spartans" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/6103b47a2d29570004bc56f2.png",
                      "Utah Utes" = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/5859a2df4f6ae202fedf28ec.png",
                      "Seattle Kraken" = "https://brandlogos.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/seattle_kraken-logo-brandlogos.net_-512x512.png",
                      "Michigan Wolverines" = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Michigan_Wolverines_Block_M.png"
  ))

for (i in seq(nrow(states))) {
  logo <- logos$png[logos$State == states$State[i]]
  shape <- states[i, ] 
  img <- rasterpic_img(shape, logo, mask = TRUE)
  plot <- plot + geom_spatraster_rgb(data = img)
}

plot
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this breakdown....It helps a bit. I am still just a little confused on what exactly to apply for my dataset, but I edited to put my data for January at the bottom. Would you be able to take a second look?

Comment: It should work with your own `January` data frame too. Just create the `logos` vector and run the loop.

Comment: @user14452102 see my update for running the code using your own data

Comment: I think I'm one bug away from fixing this and getting it running. I just edited my code in the question to show what I currently have with your help. Can you tell me if there's any line I need to omit with your new edits? As of now I'm getting an atomic vectors error.

Comment: @user14452102 I had changed the code so that it worked with your original set-up exactly as it was up until the loop. I only made the `logos` vector because I didn't originally have your `January` frame. Put your code back the way it was and just substitute my code in where your loop was.

Comment: Thanks! It's mostly all done now - everything's mapping. The only issue I see is that January frame I had is giving the states the wrong team name. January <- data.frame(ShipState = states$State,
                      Team = names(logos)[sample(length(logos), 49)]) . Is there a way to fix that so the mapping is correct? Then it should be done. Seems to randomize it?

Comment: @user14452102 we're talking at cross purposes here. I used your original `January` data frame in the above edited answer. You do not need to remake this. If you roll back your code to the original version you had when I first answered the question (when the teams and pngs were inside a switch statement) but just replace the final loop by my exact code above, then it should work. `logos` should be the original `logos` data frame. Don't use any code from the answer before my edit.

Comment: @user14452102 I have added an edit to remove any confusion. This entire script is self contained, including a copy of your original January data frame. If you run that script in a fresh R session, you will get your plot.